# Why is overflow-y ignored in this layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello everyone I have a layout made with flexbox that consist in a header, a content that fills all the remaining space and a box inside the content.
You can see the basic code here:

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
      Box<br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0gm3w9yo/

The question is, when you reduce the window height to trigger the scrollbar (so less than the yellow box height), why the

```
.content {
    overflow-y: auto;
    ....
}
```

is ignored?

I would like to have a scrollbar to scroll the .content, but not the .header. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to give it a height.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is overflow-y ignored in this layout?

Because you told it to not be able to shrink with `flex: 1 0 auto`

Change to `flex: 1 1 auto`

```css
html, body { margin: 0 }

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;                     /*  changed flex-shrink to 1  */
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

A second problem will be with the `justify-content: center; align-items: center;`, which will create an overflow at top/bottom (or left/right) when too big, so use auto margins on the flex item instead

Src: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-justify-content-center

```css
html, body { margin: 0 }

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;                     /*  changed flex-shrink to 1  */
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;            /*  IE fix  */
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;                      /*  instead of margin on the item  */
}

.box {
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
  HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>
    Box<br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works very well but I have another question: with margin: auto the two div touch each other, what if I want that margin and an extra 20px of distance between the two divs?

Comment: @ste You mean between the green and blue?

Comment: No, basically the yellow box when the window is reduced in height at some point touch the green topbar. I would like to keep a minimum of 20px between the header and the box, no matter the height of the window!

Comment: @ste In above sample I added a padding on `content` to compensate for the previous margin set on the `box`. Or you mean the whole scroll area should be moved down with 20px?

Comment: Oh I noticed now! With the padding I solve the problem :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Provide `.box` with a height. In the snippet below I have used `vh`.

Then move the `overflow` property to the `.box`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eb7814r/2/)

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
  max-height: 50vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
      Box<br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the style of your `.header` and `.content`

You need to fix the height of your header first by adding `flex-basis: 50px;`
then you set your content part `flex-basis: auto;`

```
.header {
    /* flex: 0 1 auto; */
    /* height: 50px; */
    background-color: green;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}


.content {
    /* flex: 1 0 auto; */
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```css
.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
    /* flex: 0 1 auto; */
    /* height: 50px; */
    background-color: green;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}


.content {
    /* flex: 1 0 auto; */
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="header">
    HEADER
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box">
      Box<br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br> Box
      <br>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```